# Are primary ideals always contained in unique maximal ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, commutative-algebra

Just wondering, is this a standard fact? I notice a couple Banach algebra texts define primary ideals in this way. Another question: does this property, i.e. being contained in a unique maximal ideal, characterize proper primary ideals in a commutative ring with identity?

Comment: if radical of an ideal is maximal then it is primary with condition you want . maybe  the radical of ideals you saw were maximal.

Answer (score 8):

Any prime ideal is primary. $(0)$ is prime in any integral domain. There are integral domains with more than one maximal ideal.

For a more interesting answer, consider $k[x,y]$ and the ideal $(x)$. As before, $(x)$ prime implies $(x)$ is primary. Now $(x)$ is contained in many maximal ideals, for example $(x, y-a)$ where $a \in k$.

Answer (score 3):

On the geometric side of things, the points of an irreducible affine variety are in one-to-one correspondence with the maximal ideals containing the prime ideal defining the variety. Thus any irreducible affine variety with more than one point produces a counter-example.

Comment: In other words, every prime ideal contained in more than one maximal produces a counter-example. (A little too vague in my opinion, but it doesn't matter.)

Comment: @user26857 I wasn't posting this as a proof, rather as a source of intuition. If one is struggling "guessing" the truth value of "every prime ideal is contained in a unique maximal ideal" then perhaps it is easier for him or her to grasp the equivalent statement "every irreducible variety has exactly one point". Of course, once one decides whether or not the statement is true, then he or she is charged with the task of actually proving or producing a counter-example. In some sense, this is the whole point of equivalences of categories--to make complicated statements easier to understand.

Answer (score 2):

In a commutative ring $A$ an ideal $\mathfrak q$ is defined to be primary if in the quotient ring $\,A/\mathfrak q$ zero-divisors are nilpotent.

If $A$ is noetherian, then the radical of $\mathfrak q$ is a prime ideal $\mathfrak p$, which consists of all zero-divisors modulo $\mathfrak q$.

*Example:* let $K$ be a field; in the ring $K[X,Y]$, the ideal $(X^3)$ is $(X)$-primary. It is contained in any maximal that contains $X$, e. g. $(X, Y)$, $(X, Y-1)$ and more generally $(X, p(Y))$, where $p(Y)$ is any irreducible polynomial in $K[Y]$.

Similarly, $(X^3,Y^2)$ is $(X,Y)$-primary.

Comment: This does not seem to answer the question.

Comment: @RghtHndSd: It answered virtually  by showing what is exactly a primary ideal (which was part of the question: does the mentioned property characterise primary ideals?). I've just given some more details.